# nvidia-smi returns error message with nvidia driver 470 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, cuda, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-settings

When using `nvidia-smi`

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

when using `nvidia-settings`

> ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system

relevant info:

- model: Dell xps 15 9560
- cpu: i7-7700HQ
- gpu: Geforce GTX 1050 mobile
- ubuntu version: 20.04
- kernel: 5.4.196
- driver: 470

This setup worked previously but i think a recent update to either the driver or the kernel broke it.

I already tried

- Purging and uninstalling all of the nvidia drivers several times and installing them in several different ways.
- setting nvidia as prime (also setting cpu as prime and then back)
- Updating the kernel. It would not update further than 5.4.*
- Disabling secure boot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After trying everything related to my issue i decided to try to upgrade my ubuntu version, as this previously fixed issues when i upgraded from 18.* to 20.*. Upgrading to version 22.* fixed the issue!

Here's a guide that shows how to upgrade ahead of time:
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-22-04-lts